# Need a solution for storing values in a php array using ajax in yii

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, yii

I have this ajax call

```
<script>
function add(serviceId){
$.ajax({
    url: "<?php echo Yii::app()->createUrl($bus->url.'/serAjax'); ?>",
    type: "POST",
    data: {"serviceId": serviceId},

    success: function(result){         
        $("#services").append(result);
    },
    error: function (){
        alert('Error');
   }
  });
}
```

the ajax calls this page

```
if(isset($_POST['serviceId']))
    {

       $serviceId = $_POST['serviceId'];

    }
    $service = Services::model()->findByPk($serviceId);

    $all = array();
    $ids = array();
    //add services to array
    array_push($all, $service->title);
    array_push($ids, $service->id);

    Yii::app()->session['serviceId'] = $ids;

    foreach ($all as $a){
        echo '<li class="list-group-item">'.$a.'</li>';
    }
```

A user can click multiple service options and every time they do this ajax is called. Now what I want to happen is every time a user add a service, it stores the service ids  in the $ids = array(); But whats happening is that every time the ajax call is made, it empties out the array only leaving the last selected service. I need it to retain all the ids.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try like this,

```
if(Yii::app()->session['serviceId'])
    $ids  =  Yii::app()->session['serviceId'];
else
    $ids = array();
```

Answer (score 0):

You should store these values using the built-in function setState, like this

```
Yii::app()->user->setState('serviceId', $ids);
```

instead of:

```
    Yii::app()->session['serviceId'] = $ids;
```

and then use getState to get the value back

Answer (score 0):

This is just an idea may be some better solution will be there.

Each time a request is made array will be created again and previous values will be lost. Instead you can  use some solution involving session.

Like  declare session based array on top somewhere so that it is not created again

```
$_SESSION['all'] = array();
$_SESSION['ids'] = array();

//add services to array
array_push(  $_SESSION['all'], $service->title);
array_push($_SESSION['ids'], $service->id);
```